# Wordpress - How can I edit the header of a template?

Tags: php, wordpress, layout, themes

I am new in the using Wordpress. I downloaded [this](http://www.web2feel.com/gordon/) theme and because my title of the website is too long, I need to change the header of this theme.

So I went into

> wp-content/themes/Gordon/header.php

I tried to update this file, but the changes I made didn't appear on the page. So I delete the entire content of this file (blank file), and when I reloaded the homepage - again - nothing has changed, no error, just nothing.

So I would like to ask you, how can I update the header of an installed theme in Wordpress.

Comment: Try editing the header in your browser. In Chrome you can Inspect Element and change the code. Odds are you'll be able to solve it by playing with the css.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up your header.php, best way to solve it is to open the header.php from the original theme (download) and copy/paste the code to your header.php that's online, using FTP.

Create a Child theme using One-click child theme plugin, copy the header.php into this child theme using an FTP connection again.

Then make your edits here or add a style.css to edit the header using css.

**Useful links**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/one-click-child-theme/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Designing_Headers